# Регулярное выражение для получения значений внутри скобок

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, typescript

Имеется строка `"(word1 и word2) и word3"`. Мне необходимо получить `["word1 и word2", "и", "word3"]`

**Еще парочка примеров:**

Имеется: `"(word1 и (word2 и word3)) и word4"`.
Ожидается: `["word1 и (word2 и word3)", "и", "word4"]`

Имеется: `"(word1 и (word2 и word3)) и (word4 и (word5 и word6))"`.
Ожидается: `["word1 и (word2 и word3)", "и", "word4 и (word5 и word6)"]`